# MongoDB one-to-many - array of IDs or ID ref on child model?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design

Specifically, I'm thinking of a chat app, where a `User` has many `Chat`s and each `Chat` has many `Message`s. How would I express the `Chat --has-Many--> Message` relationship?

Initially, I thought I'd store the list of `Message` ID references on `Chat`, e.g. a `Chat` document could look something like

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('507f191e810c19729de860d5'),
  title: 'Jack V, Kyle R, Sam P',
  messages: [ObjectId('507f191e810c19729de860ea'), ...],
  createdAt: 1546284204867
}
```

This way, I'd need to `$push` to the array every time a message is sent, or `$pull` if it's deleted. Makes the code somewhat more complex and obscure, but still doable.

Then I read from [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) that this approach is only tenable when the array is *small* and has a *limited growth*. *To avoid mutable, growing arrays*, it's better that `Message` retains a `chatId` ref back to its parent `Chat`

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('507f191e810c19729de860ea'),
  body: 'Hey Kyle! Mind if I ask ya a favor?',
  chatId: ObjectId('507f191e810c19729de860d5'),
  createdAt: 1546284204869
}
```

In the end, if I want to fetch messages for a chat with Mongoose,

```
const chatId = '507f191e810c19729de860d5'

// 1. through IDs array
Chat.findById(chatId).populate('messages').execPopulate()

// or

// 2. through ID ref
Message.find({ chatId })
```

From my understanding,

- 1st is more efficient, b/c it takes an array of IDs and quickly locates the `Message` documents, and *only then* reads them
- 2nd is less efficient, b/c it *has* to read *all* `Message` documents (potentially, millions) and compare `chatId` attribute on each

This in keeping with the fact that *reads* are much more expensive in MongoDB than *writes*. Am I correct is asserting that? If so, why are most resources recommending approach #2? I see it in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose#Working_with_related_documents_%E2%80%94_population) (see yellow box), in *50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developers*, and in MongoDB docs.

With one-to-many relationships, is it better to maintain an array of IDs on parent model, or rather have an ID ref on each child model?

Comment: P.S. How is this considered opinion-based? The question addresses a very specific scenario with two possible solutions. The answer is hardly if at all based on opinion, and is rather grounded in facts and metrics. This is no different than asking, should I use `location.replace` vs `location.href`. Every question on this site is opinion-based to some degree. So how does this one stand out in particular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writes for updates are actually pretty expensive. Inserting a new document is fast, but updating takes some time because you perform a read *and* a write. If `O(r)` is time complexity for "read" and `O(w)` is time complexity for "write", then update is `O(r+w)`. Reads are also actually incredibly efficient if you have an index built on the field(s) you're querying, anyway, so it's generally not something you need to be concerned about. The general advice to follow is to keep your updates to a minimum, whereas reads and inserts are fine, although none of those operations are really a problem as long as your indexing is good.

That aside, I don't recommend denormalizing your `Message`s into the `Chat` document. Documents are limited to a 16MB size cap, so if the chat gets particularly large, then MongoDB won't be able to handle it. Even if it never exceeds that limit, you can't optimize the message retrieval--any time you want to load the chat, you need to grab all of the messages at once, but in most realistic scenarios you only need to retrieve e.g. the last few dozen messages and load more as needed! Additionally, keeping your messages as separate documents will allow you to do other helpful tasks, like searching for and displaying only the messages a specific person has sent, skipping to certain points of time, purging all documents older than a given date, creating a TTL index to auto-delete older messages, etc.

So, in terms of potential functionality, performance, document size limitations, and even just ease of management, having separate `Message` documents with parent references to their corresponding `Chat` is the preferred method.

Comment: Excellent answer! Would you say that setting an index on `chatId`  in `Message` should speed up the reads given a particularly large set of documents (e.g. millions)?

Comment: Absolutely! I've worked on a production database with millions of documents in a single collection and as long as the proper indexing is in place, reads are snappy (i.e. nearly instantaneous). The problem is when you don't have that indexing in place, resulting in a full collection scan, which will typically eat up resources or even time out. This is a problem with all databases, however, and is just a fundamental limitation of large data sets. So just make sure to get those indexes in place :)